# multiline Entry() in tkinter (and customtkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry, customtkinter

```
text_promt = ctk.CTkEntry(settings, font=("Helvetica", 15),width=290, height=200)
    text_promt.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.7, anchor=ctk.CENTER)
```

Here is the simply Entry using custom tkinter.
I want the user input text to start from top left corner and loop when it reaches the right side.
So it would work literally as stack overflows website question entry or basically any websites entry.
The results I have now is the text being shown in the center, and whatever you right will forever go to the right and not loop back.

Im not sure what to try. Im expecting the text to loop back like in regular text input in regular websites or social media.

Comment: justify="left" works to start text from leftmost side. But it still doesn't make it start from top left

Comment: Do you mean that it's a multiline entry? If so, unfortunately, the only way you can have an entry field with multiple lines is through a `CTkTextbox`. I did a lot of research, and even dug into the source code. But I found nothing. There is no way to have a `CTkEntry` with multiple lines.

Comment: An entry widget can only hold a single line of text. If you need multiple lines, you need to use a `Text` widget.

Answer (score 0):

Very sorry.. Literally I just had to use textbox instead... I mixed up the names and completely forgot about texbox existence.. I was pretty sleepy..